# Not to lose session under Ion Auth, Codeigniter 3.1

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

Using Ion Auth, Version: 2.5.2, Codeigniter : 3.1.0-dev

under development on my local comp I want to set expiration time to long time, not to lose my session and for this in application/config/ion_auth.php I have:

```
$config['hash_method']    = 'bcrypt';   // sha1 or bcrypt,  bcrypt is STRONGLY recommended
$config['default_rounds'] = 8;      // This does not apply if random_rounds is set to true
$config['random_rounds']  = FALSE;
$config['min_rounds']     = 5;
$config['max_rounds']     = 9;
$config['salt_prefix']    = '$2y$';

$config['default_group']              = 'Members';           // Default group, use name
$config['admin_group']                = 'Admin';             // Default administrators group, use name
$config['identity']                   = 'email';             // A database column which is used to login with
$config['min_password_length']        = 6;                   // Minimum Required Length of Password
$config['max_password_length']        = 20;                  // Maximum Allowed Length of Password
$config['email_activation']           = FALSE;               // Email Activation for registration
$config['manual_activation']          = FALSE;               // Manual Activation for registration
$config['remember_users']             = TRUE;                // Allow users to be remembered and enable auto-login
//$config['user_expire']                = 986500;               // How long to remember the user (seconds). Set to zero for no expiration
$config['user_expire']                = 0;               // I HOPE no expiration
$config['user_extend_on_login']       = TRUE;               // Extend the users cookies every time they auto-login
$config['track_login_attempts']       = FALSE;               // Track the number of failed login attempts for each user or ip.
$config['track_login_ip_address']     = TRUE;                // Track login attempts by IP Address, if FALSE will track based on identity. (Default: TRUE)
$config['maximum_login_attempts']     = 3;                   // The maximum number of failed login attempts.
$config['lockout_time']               = 600;                 // The number of seconds to lockout an account due to exceeded attempts
$config['forgot_password_expiration'] = 0;                   // The number of milliseconds after which a forgot password request will expire. If
```

In my application/config/config.php :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 9997200; // long period of time
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 990000; // long period of time
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

But anyway in 1 hour ( or maybe a bit more ) I lose my session and have to login again.
Which params have I to set? Can it be some server options?

Thanks!

Comment: You should set absolute path of location where session files will be stored. It has to be writable location.

Answer (score 0):

From the Configuration Options Section of Ion Auth Documentation I got this :

$config['user_expire'] - Sets how long to remember the user for in seconds. DEFAULT is '86500'.

Tell me if that helped ... cheers